# Sockets- Disconnecting a client when server disconnects

Tags: java, sockets

I am programming a chat app with sockets in Java. I have this method that gets called for as many times as there are clients connected to the server.

---

```
public class ClientInfo implements Serializable
{
    public ObjectOutputStream writer;
    public ObjectInputStream reader;
    public String user_name;

    public ClientInfo(ObjectOutputStream writer, ObjectInputStream reader, String name)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.writer = writer;
        this.user_name = name;
    }
}//end class
```

---

```
 /*Client side code*/
  void remove_online_user(ClientInfo client_to_remove)
        {
            try
            {
                client_to_remove.reader.close(); //this should trigger server handler in client
                client_to_remove.writer.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//end remove_online_users()
```

---

---

On the client side, I create a `ClientInfo` object like this

---

```
client = new ClientInfo(
                    new ObjectOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()),
                    new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()),
                    user_name);

 new ServerHandler(client, this);
```

---

And finally, the ServerHandler (sorry for pasting all the code, I am trying my best to condense it as much as possible)

```
class ServerHandler implements Runnable
{
    private ClientInfo server;
    private ClientBackEnd client_back_end;


    public ServerHandler(ClientInfo server, ClientBackEnd client_back_end)
    {
        this.server = server;
        this.client_back_end = client_back_end;
    }//end constructor


    /*method invoked by start() call in constructor, manages communication between client and server*/
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            MessageInfo message;
            while ((message = (MessageInfo) server.reader.readObject()) != null)
            {
                if (message.clients != null)
                {
                    for (ClientInfo cd : message.clients)
                    {
                        if (client_back_end.listModel.contains(cd)) continue;
                        client_back_end.listModel.addElement(cd);
                    }

                    for (Object cd : client_back_end.listModel.toArray())
                    {
                        if (message.clients.contains(cd)) continue;
                        client_back_end.listModel.removeElement(cd);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                   System.out.println("\n" + message.message_contents);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)
        {
            //This should trigger during the execution of remove_online_user();
            client_back_end.disconnect_from_server(); 
        }
    }//end run()
```

**My goal::**

When the user stops the server, all clients must be disconnected. During remove_online_user(), closing the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream should trigger an exception in the clients server Handler. But it currently does not. What am I doing wrong?

(I apologize in advance if I did not post enough information; I don't want to flabbergast anyone with 4 entire .java files. Please let me know if more information is needed)

Answer (score 0):

Closing the socket will trigger an `EOFException` in the peer's `readObject()` method.

For the same reason, your read loop is invalid. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream.

Comment: Hm, I know that EOFException is a subclass of IOException and that it will trigger this exception. I don't understand what you mean when you say that readObject() doesn't return null at the end of stream? Can you please explain?

Comment: It seems a perfectly clear statement to me. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: "at the end of the stream" is what I don't understand. For what reason does it not return null? How does this answer my question?

Comment: If you know end of stream will trigger `EOFException` why are you asking me why it doesn't return null? It doesn't return null (a) *because* it throws `EOFException` and (b) because it doesn't say anything about returning null at end of stream in the Javadoc. It can return null any time you wrote a null. That's *why* it throws `EOFException`: an out-of-band value is required. Your code and your symptoms are not consistent with how these methods really work.

Comment: Okay, I understand that part now. Can you offer a solution? I don't see how to trigger a disconnect

Comment: You *have* triggeered a disconnect. You closed the stream. That closed the socket. If the method ever executed. Which at the moment is in doubt.